# Iframe loading misunderstanding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I made a simple **[test](http://jsbin.com/adurew/2/edit) **

i have 10 `<p>` elements.

after the first element i have a script : 
which created 10 `Iframes` with `SRc` , and appending them to the first

element.

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
       var t=$("<iframe />").css({'width':'50px','height':'50px'}).attr('src','http://www.msdn.com');
        $("#hello").append(t);
      }
```

strange , but i do see the other 9 `<p>`  , *before* the complete loading of the whole iframes...

should'nt the addition of new elements ( the iframes) into the Page elements  should block subsequent html rendering ?
*(plus  , as we know , javascript is a single threaded )*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. *JavaScript* is single-threaded, but that doesn't mean that the browser can't launch more than one HTTP request concurrently. Consider that images also load via concurrent HTTP requests.

Adding an `<iframe>` to the document *starts* an HTTP request, but — *because* JavaScript is single-threaded — the code does not wait for that to finish.

Comment: it starts a request  but doesnt wait ? sound strange for non threading environmenmt

Comment: Again, there's nothing that says the whole *browser* is single-threaded. The JavaScript environment on a single page is indeed single-threaded, but that has nothing to do with how the browser handles making HTTP requests.

Comment: No. The HTTP request is started, but it's a network operation - the browser process does not wait for the response. When the response *does* come back, the browser will handle it. It's just like how things work in something like Node.js.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Think about how AJAX works: you start the HTTP request, but then processing continues without waiting for the response.